# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager)

Tags: java

I tried to configure log4j with `log4j.properties' file.

All work but but I caught some strange warning:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Here's my Log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=Debug, FILE

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/Logger.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=info
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p::%d{yyyy-MM-dd}::%d{ABSOLUTE}::%c{1}::%L - %m%n
```

I am using the below class to load Log4j.properties:

```
public class Loader {

    static final Properties Log4j = new Properties();
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Loader.class);

    static {
        try {

            // loading log4j properties file
            Log4j.load(new FileInputStream("resources\\Log4j.properties"));
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(Log4j);
            logger.info("Logger initiated successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: Log4j 1 is EOL since mid-2015. Log4j 1 will not work correctly with Java 9. It's recommended to upgrade to Log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

The File is not found by the load because you try to do a FileInputStream with a relative path.

Option 1:
If you want to use your file change to

```
Log4j.load(Loader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/Log4j.properties"));
```

Option 2 (preferred):
Change the leading L to a lowercase l like log4j.properties

Then you can remove the configuration because this ist the default filename.

```
Log4j.load(new FileInputStream("resources\\Log4j.properties"));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(Log4j);
```